# Given two i.i.d. standard uniform RV $U,V$ on $(0,1)$, compute the conditional expectation $E((U-V)^+ \mid U)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

> **Problem:** Let $U,V$ be two i.i.d. standard uniform RV on $(0,1)$, compute  $E((U-V)^+ \mid U)$

---

**My solution:**

We choose $Z \in L^\infty (\Omega, \sigma(U), \mathbb{P}) \iff Z=f(U)$ for some bounded borel measurable function $f$ and want to compute $$E(\max(U-V,0)f(U))= \int_{(0,1)^2} \max(u-v,0) f(u)dudv  \\ = \int_{(0,1)^2} \max(u-v,0)1_{u-v>0} f(u) du dv + \underbrace{\int_{(0,1)^2} \max(u-v,0)1_{u-v \leq 0}f(u)dudv}_{=0} \\ \overset{(*)}=\int_0^1\int_0 ^u uf(u)dvdu-\int_0^1 \int_0^u vf(u)dvdu =\int_0^1 u^2f(u)du- \int_0^1 \frac{u^2}{2}f(u)du  \\ = \int_0^1 \frac{u^2}{2}f(u)du = E((U^2/2)f(U)) $$ 
From which I conclude that $$ E((U-V)^+ \mid U)= U^2/2 $$
I did omit some details about the use of Fubini-Tonelli's Theorem in (*), but indeed with $f$ being bounded the use of this theorem is justified.

---

**Question:** Is my solution correct? If not, please highlight my mistake and try pointing me towards the right solution. Unfortunately I can't ask my tutors this week and I don't want to fall behind on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E((U-V)^+ \mid U) = \int_0^1 (U-x)^+dx= \int_0^U (U-x)dx
=\frac{U^2}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks @Did. That looks much better.

Comment: Nice answer, +1.

Comment: I am sure this answer is correct, since I am very new to the conditional expectation I can only guess that some proposition was involved in calculating this. However, my question written in bold in the OP wasn't strictly answered. Maybe I should reformulate "Is my solution correct?" to "Is this the correct way to approach the solution when only working with the definition of the conditional expectation?"

Comment: Your answer is correct and is also a good approach, though I prefer some simple approach as above.